# Como criar um "player" musical em C#?

Tags: c#

Estou criando um player de música em C#. A parte do design (*sliders*, barra de volume, etc.) está toda criada, mas falta o código!

Como posso fazer o sistema de músicas de forma que quando clico no *play* ele executa a música, no *pause* pause a música e no *stop* pare a música?

Comment: Primeiro de tudo, quais frameworks está usando? Windows Forms, WPF, outro?

Comment: O que você tem até o momento? Somente o DESIGN? Aí complica amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, pelo pouco que você postou, você pode dar uma verificada neste [artigo](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/csharp/c-for-beginners-make-your-own-mp3-player-free/), que ensina, com uma biblioteca nativa do Windows, como fazer um player, com a possibilidade de `Play` e `Stop`, caso você queira algo mais sofisticado, você já tem um caminho pra seguir.

Encontrei um outro [artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16316/Audio-Player-using-winmm-dll-and-WPL-File), mais sofisticado, para a mesma proposta, vale a pena conferir.

Comment: Se acharem interessante, eu faço a tradução da ambos os artigos e posto aqui.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode dar uma olhada na biblioteca [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio). Esse exemplo mostra [como dar play em um arquivo mp3](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/wiki/Playing-an-Audio-File#loading-the-file).

A interface `IWavePlayer` possui métodos `Stop()` `Play()` e `Pause()`.

Isso já deve dar conta da parte de reprodução das músicas.

Comment: Já utilizei a biblioteca em um projeto pessoal e a recomendo.

Answer (score 0):

Para a programação de um player de música você vai precisar de [codecs](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec), DLLs que decodificam ou codificam o som para que seja tocado.

Se você não sabe nada de programação em C#, recomendo que você procure apostilas, baixe o Visual C# e comece do 0, depois tente criar o Player. Se já possui leia sobre codecs e baixe as DLLs dos codecs que seu programa precisará.